# Como ler a largura e altura de um arquivo físico do tipo imagem?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, imagem, drawing

Como obter o `width` e `height` de um arquivo físico do tipo imagem?

Comment: Que formato está o arquivo? Que tecnologia de imagem está usando?

Comment: @bigown jpeg e png. Se puder ser algo mais genérico que aborde vários formatos me ajudaria ainda mais. No entanto jpeg e png já são suficiente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode obter essas informações usando a classe [`Image`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), através das propriedades [`Height`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.height?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Image_Height) e [`Width`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.width?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Image_Width).

```
var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\Path\1.jpg");
MessageBox.Show("Width: " + img.Width + ", Height: " + img.Height);
```

[**Fonte**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456015/1608936)

Answer (score 4):

Pode para alguns formatos suportados:

```
var imagem = Image.FromFile("teste.jpg");
var largura = imagem.Width;
var altura = imagem.Height;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetImageMetadata.cs).

Conforme a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Drawing_Image_FromFile_System_String_) é possível abrir BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG e TIFF.